# how to restrict UItext field as a numric keyboard in ios?

Tags: ios

how to restrict UItext field as a numric in ios ?

It allow me all the type of keyboard but I want to restrict it for phone number.

Comment: Change keyboard type from default to number pad .

Comment: Google it. Cause its very basic

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ Simply setting the keyboard type is not enough. A user can paste other text into the text field.

Comment: you are right maddy .... He should use regular expression , via using textfield delegates ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the keyboard type for the textField directly from the interface builder as shown in screenshot. You can use UIKeyboardTypePhonePad or UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad as per your need.

Also you can use this code :

```
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypePhonePad];
```

[image]

Comment: This is not enough. A user can still paste non-numeric text into the text field.

Comment: thanks ..thats what I want ...